# filter dataframe and add the newly created columns to original df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Is there a simple way to perform calculations for each fruit in turn, adding the newly created column to original df?

```
df
 concatted  score      fruit        status   date              
 apple_bana  0.500      apple       high    2010-02-20         
      apple  0.600      apple      low     2010-02-21          
     banana  0.530      pear       low     2010-01-12
```

```
Expected output:
 concatted  score      fruit        status   date              first_diff  
 apple_bana  0.500      apple       high    2010-02-20                     
      apple  0.600      apple      low     2010-02-21            0.1
     banana  0.530      pear       low     2010-01-12
```

```
I tried:
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pair']
for fruit in fruits :
    selected_rows = df[(df['fruit'] == fruit)]
    selected_rows['first_diff']= df.score.diff().dropna()
    df = df.append(selected_rows)
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: it's shown in the middle

Comment: df.groupby('fruit').score.diff()  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby()`, and apply `.diff()` to score

```
df['first_diff']=df[['concatted', 'score', 'fruit', 'status', 'date']].groupby('fruit')['score'].diff().fillna('')
```

If in need of something general please try;

```
df['first_diff']=df[[x for x in df.columns]].groupby('fruit')['score'].diff().fillna('')

     concatted  score  fruit status    date       first_diff
0  apple_bana   0.50  apple   high  2010-02-20           
1       apple   0.60  apple    low  2010-02-21        0.1
2      banana   0.53   pear    low  2010-01-12
```